# How to float an element next to a possible right scrollbar?

Tags: css

I want my page elements to stay in the same position regardless of whether there's a scrollbar on the right edge or not. I've managed to accomplish this for the main content by giving the body `100vw` and by giving the main content a `margin-right` of the width of the scrollbar. (Assume, for simplicity's sake, that the width of the scrollbar is fixed at 16px.) But I can't figure out how to make content on the right stick to where the scrollbar's left edge will be.

In the example below, the "Right" text should not change position when the scrollbar appears, and all of its text should remain visible without hard-coding its `left` (since that would have to be changed every time the width of its content changed).

```js
const { style } = main;
setInterval(() => {
  // simulating lots of main content
  style.height = style.height ? '' : '1000px';
}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 40px; /* because the "Result" gets in the way */
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}
#right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
#right > div {
  margin-right: 16px; /* SCROLLBAR WIDTH */
}

#main {
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-right: 16px; /* SCROLLBAR WIDTH */
}
#main > div {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id=right>
  <div>
    Right
  </div>
</div>
<div id=main>
  <div>
    Main content (does not change position)
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried lots of combinations of `float: right`, `position: absolute`, `margin-right` and `right` properties on the elements, and tried nesting another container on the right, but nothing gave me the desired result. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use left not right with `vw` unit and rectify with a translation:

```js
const { style } = main;
setInterval(() => {
  // simulating lots of main content
  style.height = style.height ? '' : '1000px';
}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 40px; /* because the "Result" gets in the way */
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}
#right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100vw; /* all the way to the left */
  transform:translateX(calc(-1*(100% + 16px))); /* move back considering 100% of its width and scrollbar width*/
}
#right > div {
  margin-right: 16px; /* SCROLLBAR WIDTH */
}

#main {
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-right: 16px; /* SCROLLBAR WIDTH */
}
#main > div {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id=right>
  <div>
    Right
  </div>
</div>
<div id=main>
  <div>
    Main content (does not change position)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. It seems a bit odd to have to specify `left` and then transform to move it back, but it works, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Snow it seems to be the only to avoid the scroll effect. You need to consider the left reference and not the right one